# How do I export a PFX Code Signing Key to SPC and PVK under Windows 7?

Tags: code-signing

I have a code signing key in PFX format that I need to export into SPC and PVK files.  I tried to install the OpenSSL from Shining light but the install fails under Windows 7.

http://www.shininglightpro.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Here are the instructions I am using from Comodo as a basis:
https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=1089

Anyone know of an alternate way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the instructions here:

http://help.godaddy.com/article/6034

You still need openssl though, I guess you need to fix that.

Tim

Comment: I am using 64-bit as well. Wasn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Link from @timanderson worked great for me. 2 notes:

- My Firefox saves the pkcs12 file with extension p12 and not pfx.
- If you need a pvk without password, add the flag -nocrypt to pvk.